# Get last element of array by parsing JSON with Neo4j APOC

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Short task description: I need to get the last element of an array/list of one of the fields in nested JSON, here the input JSON file:

```
{
    "origin": [{
            "label": "Alcohol drinks",
            "tag": [],
            "type": "string",
            "xpath": []
        },
        {
            "label": "Wine",
            "tag": ["red", "white"],
            "type": "string",
            "xpath": ["Alcohol drinks"]
        },
        {
            "label": "Port wine",
            "tag": ["Portugal", "sweet", "strong"],
            "type": "string",
            "xpath": ["Alcohol drinks", "Wine"]
        },
        {
            "label": "Sandeman Cask 33",
            "tag": ["red", "expensive"],
            "type": "string",
            "xpath": ["Alcohol drinks", "Wine", "Port wine"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get the last element of "xpath" field, in order to create relationship with appropriate "label". Here is the code, which creates connection to all elements mentioned in "xpath", I need just connection to the last one:

```
WITH "file:///D:/project/neo_proj/input.json" AS url 
CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value 
UNWIND value.origin as or 
MERGE(label:concept{name:or.label}) 
ON CREATE SET label.type = or.type 
FOREACH(tagName IN or.tag | MERGE(tag:concept{name:tagName}) 
MERGE (tag)-[r:link]-(label) 
ON CREATE SET r.Weight=1 
ON MATCH SET r.Weight=r.Weight+1)  
FOREACH(xpathName IN or.xpath | MERGE (xpath:concept{name:xpathName})
                                MERGE (label)-[r:link]-(xpath))
```

Probably there is something like:

```
apoc.agg.last(or.xpath)
```

which returns just an array of arrays or all "xpath" from all 4 records of "origin".

I will appreciate any help, probably there some workarounds (not necessary as I proposed) to solve this issue. Thank you in advance!

N.B. All this should be done from an app, not from within Neo4j browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the `last()` function? This will return the last element of a list.

In this case, since you UNWIND the origin to 4 rows, you'll get the last element of the list for each of those rows.

```
WITH "file:///D:/project/neo_proj/input.json" AS url 
CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value 
UNWIND value.origin as or 
RETURN last(or.xpath) as last
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but it returns just the last row, which is ["Alcohol drinks", "Wine", "Port wine"], not the last element of each row. My apologies for the poor explanation.

Comment: Are you running this same query, and is your input the same data as provided above? Also what version of Neo4j and APOC?

Comment: Sorry, it is too late the head is working on half of the strength, solved. Need something like (FOREACH(xpathName IN last(or.xpath) | MERGE (xpath:concept{name:xpathName}) MERGE (label)-[r:link]-(xpath)))

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to split this query into two queries if you want to only take the xpath array of the last element in the origin object.

Query: 1

```
WITH "file:///D:/project/neo_proj/input.json" AS url 
CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value 
UNWIND value.origin as or 
MERGE(label:concept{name:or.label}) 
ON CREATE SET label.type = or.type 
FOREACH(tagName IN or.tag | MERGE(tag:concept{name:tagName}) 
MERGE (tag)-[r:link]-(label) 
ON CREATE SET r.Weight=1 
ON MATCH SET r.Weight=r.Weight+1)
```

Query 2:

```
WITH "file:///D:/project/neo_proj/input.json" AS url 
CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value 
WITH value.origin[-1] as or 
MATCH(label:concept{name:or.label})
FOREACH(xpathName IN or.xpath | MERGE (xpath:concept{name:xpathName})
                                MERGE (label)-[r:link]-(xpath))
```

Combining these two queries into a single one feels hacky anyway and I would avoid it, but I guess you can do the following.

```
WITH "file:///D:/project/neo_proj/input.json" AS url 
CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value 
UNWIND value.origin as or 
MERGE(label:concept{name:or.label}) 
ON CREATE SET label.type = or.type 
FOREACH(tagName IN or.tag | MERGE(tag:concept{name:tagName}) 
MERGE (tag)-[r:link]-(label) 
ON CREATE SET r.Weight=1 
ON MATCH SET r.Weight=r.Weight+1)
// Any aggregation function will break the UNWIND loop 
// and return a single row as we want to write it only once
WITH value.origin[-1] as last, count(*) as agg
FOREACH(xpathName IN last.xpath | 
                                MERGE(label:concept{name:last.label})
                                MERGE (xpath:concept{name:xpathName})
                                MERGE (label)-[r:link]-(xpath))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and kind help. One moment, I need to take not only the xpath array of the last element, but the last element of each "xpath" row. Like this: 1 row - empty, 2 row - "Alcohol drinks", 3 row - "Wine", 4 row - "Port Wine". I am sorry, I suppose it is because of my poor explanation.

Comment: I do not know how to mark both of the answers as helpful, I do not have enough reputation. If, you know please tell me, as both of your answers helped me a lot. Anyway clicked to mark your answer as useful. Thank you for your efforts, everything solved. This thing with "last" was exactly what I needed.